# Parse String containing space into integer array

Tags: java

I have an error here with adding space into integer array. The result works fine but with throw exception error. Wonder how can I solve it?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " "
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at menu.main(menu.java:167)
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: And what number would `" "` represent?. Show us the input

Comment: Hi, all. I have an error here with adding space into integer array. The result works fine but with throw exception error. Wonder how can I solve it?

Comment: How can you add space in Integer array?

Comment: @TheLostMind binary numbers of 1 and 0. But I'm adding the space value in as well.

Comment: Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(XORMessage.charAt(t)));

Comment: Where is your code? What is your input and expected result?

Comment: Well, you can't. Spaces are not integers.

Comment: My program is about an encryption and decryption of XOR operation.
For example: 
Input string of 100 101
I parse it into integer array, encrypt it with XOR
than print it back to string. 
Output: 100 101
However, the space input is causing an error.
Is there any way to get rid of the exception error?
My result works fine.

Comment: My error lies with  "Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Message.charAt(t)));"
With a string of binary including space.
parse into integer array causing a error. Any way to resolve?

Comment: add a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). No one can guess what you want to do

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
Integer.parseInt(" "); // you are passing empty string to parse function.

int value;
if(!stringValue.trim().equals("")){
  value=Integer.parseInt(stringValue);
}
else{
 // assign the 0 value of whatever suits your requirements 
}
```

Comment: The question is not clear yet, how can you write an answer?

Comment: @Apurva it is pretty obvious from the exception..

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo You solved my problem. Thanks! That was brilliant!

Comment: It's **not** me down voted.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s="0 1 0 1 1 1 0";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("\\s+")));
}
```

O/P :

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String stringToAdd : youString.split(" "))
    output.add(Integer.parseInt(stringToAdd));
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "3 4 6 78 a 8 9";
    String[] ss = s.split(" ");
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
        try {
            int val = Integer.valueOf(ss[i]);
            list.add(val);          
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println(ss[i] + " is not a number");
        }

    }
    list.toArray();
}
```